# Pull Data Till When An Action Happens

Tags: sql-server

I have a table like below. I want to pull records by user and ignore any things that happen after the 'Delete' action. So for example, user A should only pull IDs 1-4, and user B should pull all IDs 6-9. Thank you for your help.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.  Please show us what you've tried and where you're getting stuck, including any errors you receive.  Also, please post sample data in text form instead of an img so it's easier for us to recreate your situation on our end.

Comment: What does "after the 'Delete' action" mean, are we ordering by ID or date?

Comment: @Charlieface Means only pull records till the first "Delete" happens, and ignore everything after. Yes order by ID.

Comment: @squillman Thanks for your help! Still figuring out how to post text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A window function should work nicely here.**

We just do a running conditional count of the rows which are `'Delete'`, then filter on that being 0.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN [Action] = 'Delete' THEN 1 END) OVER
            (PARTITION BY [User] ORDER BY [Id] ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS DeletedAlready
    FROM table
) t
WHERE t.DeleteAlready = 0;
```